# Using a joins query with multiple conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a query which is supposed to fetch category names based on certain conditions. Every category has a number of subcategories, and every subcategory has providers. I want to display only categories with subcategories where the number of providers is positive. So currently I am doing this:

controller

```
@categories = Category.with_providers
```

model:

```
Category.joins(subcategories: [:service_providers]).uniq
```

Based on my task What I need to show now are only Categories where service_providers count is more than 0 **and** there is at least one provider with a **published: true** property.

My legacy problem here is that Categories do not relate to service_providers.

Categories have Subcategories
Subcategories have Service Providers

This problem could be quickly solved by establishing a through connection on the Category to Provider relation, but since I have already spent some time trying to write a correct query on my initial question, I would like to know the answer to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to check for the condition `service_providers count is more than 0`, since `joins` applies an `INNER JOIN`. What you need to do is:

```
Category.joins(subcategories: [:service_providers]).where(service_providers: {published: true})
```